# React functional setState

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, state

Hi guys im trying to do functional setState in react, but i cant seem to achive it right now i have a hanlder that is supposed to set the state of this.state.siocId

```
handleChange(e) {
    const {value} = e.target;
    this.setState(state => ({
        siocId: {...state.siocId, siocId: value}
    }));
}
```

but this is setting `this.state.siocId.siocId = value`, hoy can i do to get `this.state.siocId = value`? i tried this line with no success `siocId: {...state, siocId: value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to setstate functionally, then use this pattern

```
handleChange(e) {
   const {value} = e.target;
   this.setState(function(prevState, props){
      return {siocId: value}
   });
}
```

Also refer these articles [functional-setstate](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b)
and [Function in setstae](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1) for more info

However, u should use functional setstae when the value of the state depends on the previous state. This is used because setstate calls are not run immediately

Use the below pattern if ur state is not dependent on previous state

```
handleChange(e) {
    const {value} = e.target;
    this.setState({
        siocId: value
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `functional setState` to achieve what you want, you would simple write

```
handleChange(e) {
    const {value} = e.target;
    this.setState({
        siocId: value
    });
}
```

and this would give you `this.state.siocId = value`

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating this -

```
handleChange(e) {
    const {value} = e.target;
    this.setState({
        siocId: value
    });
}
```